# Vue Cli Serve Fatal JavaScript invalid size error: node_api_throw_syntax_error

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuejs2

My problem ist, that I am not able to serve or build my  vue app. While  doing so, i get the following error:

```
INFO  Starting development server...
[70%] sealing (finish module graph ESLintWebpackPlugin_1)


#
# Fatal error in , line 0
# Fatal JavaScript invalid size error 169220804
#
#
#
#FailureMessage Object: 00000075C11FC8E0
 1: 00007FF78CD49E7F node_api_throw_syntax_error+175967
 2: 00007FF78CC6036F v8::CTypeInfoBuilder<void>::Build+11999
 3: 00007FF78DACD182 V8_Fatal+162
 4: 00007FF78D60A265 v8::internal::FactoryBase<v8::internal::Factory>::NewFixedArray+101
 5: 00007FF78D48F8E3 v8::internal::FeedbackNexus::ic_state+65795
 6: 00007FF78D4AE460 v8::Context::GetIsolate+15600
 7: 00007FF78D2FAA40 v8::internal::CompilationCache::IsEnabledScriptAndEval+25952
 8: 00007FF78D8078B1 v8::internal::SetupIsolateDelegate::SetupHeap+558193
 9: 00007FF70EB45D8E
```

I found this threat, which references the same issue, but in a single file of code:
[fatal javascript invalid size error 188720663](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75474908/fatal-javascript-invalid-size-error-188720663)

Is there any way to identify such a loop in my *.vue files or to identify, which files were processed last?

I had the error a while before, but then after changing anything it disappears (maybe a lucky hit). Using an old commit (when it had worked) also did not fix this error. I also tried to clone the repo and install it again.

Comment: Have you try to reset the node_modules? Is worth the try i thinks because the build seems stop on ```[70%] sealing (finish module graph ESLintWebpackPlugin_1)```

Comment: yeah, i did a npm ci and a whole new installing after reclone the repository.

Comment: Try maybe to run with ```--max-old-space-size=4096```, source https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/issues/18051

Comment: thanks, but I have tried this already. I am right now deep in the debugger :)
and it seems like while generation the cli-service creates an array, which exceeds memory. this happens in relation with defined vue-filters.
(maybe its a hint for someone, but this dont have to be the origin, just my current state of searching)

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution!

the issue was, that within .prettierrc the property "endOfLine" was set to "auto".

This resulted in a \r\n instead of a \r at the end of each line, which itself results to this memory leak within the vue compiler.